# Different code behavior and different LegacyIAccessible properties of COM Object on different PC's

Tags: c#, ui-automation

Im testing some c# console application that manipulates another GUI exe using UI Automation. I tested my program on 2 different machines with the same OS (win 2019 datacenter) and other software installed. The problem is: it works on one of them, but doesn't work on another.

I'm trying to get some LegacyIAccessible properties of UIAutomationElement "interface"

Here is example of my code:

```
IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern pattern = (IUIAutomationLegacyIAccessiblePattern)this.uiAutomation.GetAnyPattern(patternId, interface);
IAccessible accessible = pattern.GetIAccessible();
```

On one machine, "accessible" isn't null, and Inspect.exe shows such properties of "interface" object when I hoover over it:

```
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    "Press"
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  "Color [Red]"
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Debug"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: menu item (0xC)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    focusable (0x100000)
```

On another machine, "accessible" is null and Inspect.exe shows:

```
LegacyIAccessible.ChildId:  0
LegacyIAccessible.DefaultAction:    "Press"
LegacyIAccessible.Description:  ""
LegacyIAccessible.Help: ""
LegacyIAccessible.KeyboardShortcut: ""
LegacyIAccessible.Name: "Debug"
LegacyIAccessible.Role: push button (0x2B)
LegacyIAccessible.State:    collapsed,focusable (0x100400)
LegacyIAccessible.Value:    ""
```

On both inspects, "interface" object is showing
IsLegacyIAccessiblePatternAvailable:    true
but they show to have different roles.

And thus, I cannot get "Color" on one of the computers.

What might be the reason that automation behaves differently? Like I said, both environments are pretty much the same.

Comment: Perhaps someone found a reason or workaround?

Comment: Reason for it was some windows update, but can't really say which one.